# Trying to pull text from one field and put it into a button text

Tags: javascript, button

I have a page that I can use merge fields from a CMS to dynamically adjust content; however, this functionality doesn't work with button text. Therefore, I need to use a normal text field and then take the value from that field and push it to the button text.

I thought this would work, but something it's not working right. Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

```
<div id="ctatext" class="ctabutton">Request Pricing</div>
<input type="submit" value="Get Started" data-wait="Please wait..." id="ctabutton" class="_2-0-yellow-btn-2 request w-button">

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    let btntext = $('.ctabutton').text();
    $('input._2-0-yellow-btn-2 request w-button').val(btntext); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add a string of text into an input field when user clicks a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13941055/add-a-string-of-text-into-an-input-field-when-user-clicks-a-button)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Id's instead of the classes, since they are present.

The current selector you are using is invalid.

It should be

```html
$('input._2-0-yellow-btn-2.request.w-button').val(btntext); 
// vs
$('input._2-0-yellow-btn-2 request w-button').val(btntext);
```

```html
<div id="ctatext" class="ctabutton">Request Pricing</div>
<input type="submit" value="Get Started" data-wait="Please wait..." id="ctabutton" class="_2-0-yellow-btn-2 request w-button">

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    let btntext = $('#ctatext').text();
    console.log(btntext);
    $('#ctabutton').val(btntext); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: labee, Ah ok. I didn't realize I could use the ID. Thank you for the help, this did the trick!

Comment: My pleasure, if the answer worked, please mark it as the answer and vote up, I would appreciate it.