# How to get LAT and LNG from google map javascript to html input and add marker

Tags: javascript, html

I have a google map location picker that works fine and returns LAT and LNG but I will like to add the LAT and LNG into the HTML input field when the location is picked. Below is what my code looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Event Click LatLng</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        
function initMap() {
  const myLatlng = { lat: 24.466667, lng: 54.366669 };
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: myLatlng,
  });


  // Create the initial InfoWindow.
  let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "Click the map to get Lat/Lng!",
    position: myLatlng,
  });

  infoWindow.open(map);
  // Configure the click listener.
  map.addListener("click", (mapsMouseEvent) => {
    // Close the current InfoWindow.
    infoWindow.close();
    // Create a new InfoWindow.
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      position: mapsMouseEvent.latLng,
    });
    infoWindow.setContent(
      JSON.stringify(mapsMouseEvent.latLng.toJSON(), null, 2)
    );
    infoWindow.open(map);
  });
}

    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        
        /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" style="height: 500px;"></div>

    <!-- Async script executes immediately and must be after any DOM elements used in callback. -->
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB41DRUbKWJHPxaFjMAwdrzWzbVKartNGg&callback=initMap&v=weekly&channel=2"
      async
    ></script>

<input type="text" name="lat" id="lat">

<input type="text" name="lng" id="lng">
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see from above, there is an infoWindow that gets the LNG and LAT when a location is clicked on the map but now I want where a location is click it get the LNG to the input field`<input type="text" name="lng" id="lng">` and LAT to `<input type="text" name="lat" id="lat">`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add a string of text into an input field when user clicks a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13941055/add-a-string-of-text-into-an-input-field-when-user-clicks-a-button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your click listener:

```
document.getElementById('lat').value = mapsMouseEvent.latLng.lat();
document.getElementById('lng').value = mapsMouseEvent.latLng.lng();
```

[image]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  const myLatlng = {
    lat: 24.466667,
    lng: 54.366669
  };
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: myLatlng,
  });


  // Create the initial InfoWindow.
  let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "Click the map to get Lat/Lng!",
    position: myLatlng,
  });

  infoWindow.open(map);
  // Configure the click listener.
  map.addListener("click", (mapsMouseEvent) => {
    // Close the current InfoWindow.
    infoWindow.close();
    // Create a new InfoWindow.
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      position: mapsMouseEvent.latLng,
    });
    document.getElementById('lat').value = mapsMouseEvent.latLng.lat();
    document.getElementById('lng').value = mapsMouseEvent.latLng.lng();
    infoWindow.setContent(
      JSON.stringify(mapsMouseEvent.latLng.toJSON(), null, 2)
    );
    infoWindow.open(map);
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 80%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Event Click LatLng</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->

</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>

  <!-- Async script executes immediately and must be after any DOM elements used in callback. -->
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&v=weekly&channel=2" async></script>

  <input type="text" name="lat" id="lat">

  <input type="text" name="lng" id="lng">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Right now you have

```
infoWindow.setContent(
  JSON.stringify(mapsMouseEvent.latLng.toJSON(), null, 2)
);
```

Which as you said puts the latlng info into the infoWindow.  It sounds like that works correctly.  So it should just be a matter of adding

```
document.querySelector("#lat").value = mapsMouseEvent.latLng.lat;
document.querySelector("#lng").value = mapsMouseEvent.latLng.lng;
```

You can put that within the map.click handler, right after infoWindow.setContent, or in place of it.

Comment: where am I adding ```document.querySelector("#lat").innerText = mapsMouseEvent.latLng.lat;
document.querySelector("#lng").innerText = mapsMouseEvent.latLng.lng;``` If possible add it to the code I post to create yours.

Comment: Check the final line of my answer.

Comment: `innerText` for a text input?

Comment: @MrUpsidown good point, fixed :)